# jQuery select a specific li by giving the index?

Tags: jquery

I am just trying to highlight the first item in the list:

```
$('.foo')
    .find('li')[0]
    .css( "background-color", "yellow" );
```

.find('li') works like I expect it to by highlighting all the li, but I want to be able to select one by giving the index.

https://jsfiddle.net/zAzz8/229/

Comment: If none of the answers work or you are still facing trouble, let me know so I can help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do

```
.find('li')[0]
```

it gets the *native* javascript `DOM` element which does not have access to the jQuery `css` function.

Use [**:eq()**](https://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/) instead

```
$('.foo')
    .find('li:eq(0)')
    .css( "background-color", "yellow" );
```

```js
$('.foo')
  .find('li:eq(0)')
  .css("background-color", "yellow");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='foo'>
  <ul class="bar">
    <li class="item-i">I</li>
    <li class="item-ii">II</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `[0]` is selecting a DOM element rather than a jQuery object. You can't use the `.css()` function directly on a DOM element. Use `.eq()` instead to select the list item as a jQuery object

```
$('.foo')
    .find('li')
    .eq(0)
    .css("background-color", "yellow")
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `:eq(0)`
For example:

```
$("ul li:eq(2)").remove();
```

this code removes the Third child of the ul